# Using array to show different points on map

Tags: android

I am making an app in which i have a navigation screen where the user can give in multiple locations.
Those locations are stored in a array string.
I am using that string in my map class and i want to show al the locations on the map with a marker.
Only the last location stored in the array shows up.
Can anybody help me please.

My Navigation class

```
public class Navigatie extends Activity{

public static String plaats1;
public static String plaats2;
public GeoPoint p;
public static String[] plaats;
public int i = 0;
static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] 
         {
            "Antwerpen", "Aalst", "Aartselaar", "Brussel", "Charleroi","duinkerke", "Gent", "Hasselt", "Ieper", ""
         };

// Here we create the layout, everything that's needed on the form is loaded in here.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigatie);

    // Create an instance of the AutoCompleteTextView which is created in the layout file
     AutoCompleteTextView textView=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
     // Create an ArrayAdapter which we are using to autocomplete the textview
     ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.item_list,COUNTRIES);
     // put the adapter created above in the AutoCompleteTextView
     textView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // We create a new ImageButton which links to the map.java class 
    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    // We give a onclicklistener method to the button imageButton
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        // if the imageButton is clicked we start a new activity called "Map"
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*
            for (int j = 0; j<plaats.length; j++)
            {
                Map.plaats[j] = plaats[j];
            }
            */
            startActivity(new Intent(Navigatie.this, Map.class));
        }
    });

    Button add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toevoegen);

    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText text1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
            plaats1 = text1.getText().toString();

            if (plaats1 != "")
            {
            EditText text2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            text2.append(plaats1 + "\n");

            plaats = new String[20];
            plaats[i] = plaats1;
            Toast.makeText(Navigatie.this,  plaats[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            i++;
            text1.setText("");
            }
        }
    });

    Button clear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.verwijderen);

    clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText text2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            text2.setText("");
            Arrays.fill(plaats, null);
        }
    });
}
```

}

My Map class:

```
public class Map extends MapActivity {
private MapView mapView;
private MapController mc;
LocationManager locMgr;
MyLocationListener locLstnr;
private TextView tvlat;
private TextView tvlong;
public Navigatie nav;
public String locatie;
public int coordinates[] = new int[100];
public int counter = 0;
int gplat;
int gplon;
static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] 
     {
        "Antwerpen", "Aalst", "Aartselaar", "Brussel",    "Charleroi","duinkerke", "Gent", "Hasselt", "Ieper", ""
     };

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 // set the layout screen to map
 setContentView(R.layout.map);

 // Create an instance of the AutoCompleteTextView which is created in the layout file
 AutoCompleteTextView textView=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);
 // Create an ArrayAdapter which we are using to autocomplete the textview
 ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.item_list,COUNTRIES);
 // put the adapter created above in the AutoCompleteTextView
 textView.setAdapter(adapter);

 // Setting the mapview1 to the instance of MapView
 mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview1);
 // giving a controller to mc
 mc = mapView.getController();

 // String location2 = Navigatie.getVariable();

 for (int i = 0; i<Navigatie.plaats.length; i++)
 {
     if(Navigatie.plaats[i]!=null && !Navigatie.plaats[i].equals(""))
     {
         FindLocation(Navigatie.plaats[i]); 
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("Locatie niet gevonden");
     }
 }

 // create an instance of the find button created in the layout file
 Button btn_find = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);

 // Defining button click event listener for the find button
 OnClickListener findClickListener = new OnClickListener() 
 {
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {
         // Getting reference to EditText to get the user input location
         EditText etLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);

         // Getting user input location
         String location = etLocation.getText().toString();

         if(location!=null && !location.equals(""))
         {
             Toast.makeText(Map.this, "Inzoomend op " + location, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new GeocoderTask().execute(location);
         }
         else
         {
             Toast.makeText(Map.this, "Locatie niet gevonden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     }
 };

 // Setting button click event listener for the find button
 btn_find.setOnClickListener(findClickListener);

 // redraws the map
 mapView.invalidate();

 // sets the built in zoomcontrols on the screen
 mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

 Drawable makerDefault = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin);
 MirItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new MirItemizedOverlay(makerDefault);
 GeoPoint point = null;

 for (int i = 0; i<100; i++)
 {
     point = new GeoPoint(coordinates[i], coordinates[i+1]);
     OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "new place added", null);
     itemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem(overlayItem);
     i++;
 }
 mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
 MapController mc = mapView.getController();
 mc.setCenter(point);

 /*
String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER; 
locMgr = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locLstnr = new MyLocationListener();
locMgr.requestSingleUpdate(provider, null);
  */

 List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
 Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
```

}

```
// when the form is created we put in the menu from the resources menu.
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // we get the menu called main from the resources menu
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

// we set the options for the menu parts
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
    // if my location is touched, this code is executed
    case R.id.my_location:
         // creates a toast that displays "moving to current location"
         Toast.makeText(Map.this, "Moving To Current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER; 
            locMgr = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locLstnr = new MyLocationListener();
            locMgr.requestSingleUpdate(provider, null);
         // locLstnr.gpsCurrentLocation();
         return true;
    // if normal view is touched, this code is executed
    case R.id.normalview:
         // creates a toast that displays "Map Normal Street View"
         Toast.makeText(Map.this, "Map Normal Street View", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         // if the satellite view is enabled, we disable the satellite view so the normal view popups again
         if(mapView.isSatellite()==true){
         mapView.setSatellite(false);
         }
         return true;
    case R.id.satellite:
         // creates a toast that displays "Map Satellite view"
         Toast.makeText(Map.this, "Map Satellite View", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         // if the satellite view is disabled we enable the satellite view
         if(mapView.isSatellite()==false){
         mapView.setSatellite(true);
    }

}
return true;
```

}

```
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}


public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        String Text = "My current location is: " +
                "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +
                "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String coordinates[] = {""+loc.getLatitude(), ""+loc.getLongitude()};
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

        GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
                (int) (lat * 1E6),
                (int) (lng * 1E6));

        mc.animateTo(p);
        mc.setZoom(7);
        mapView.invalidate();


    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                "Gps Disabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                "Gps Enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
    }
}


// My overlay Class starts
class MyMapOverlays extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{   
    GeoPoint location = null;

    public MyMapOverlays(GeoPoint location)
    {
        super();
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow)
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        // translate the screen pixels
        Point screenPoint = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(this.location, screenPoint);
        //add the image
        canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pushpin),
                screenPoint.x, screenPoint.y , null); //Setting the image &nbsp;location on the screen (x,y).
    }
}
// My overlay Class ends

private class MirItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay 
{
    private List<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    public MirItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) 
    {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) 
    {
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }
    @Override
    public int size() 
    {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }
    public void addOverlayItem(OverlayItem overlayItem) 
    {
        mOverlays.add(overlayItem);
        populate();
    }
    public void addOverlayItem(int lat, int lon, String title) 
    {
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);
        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, title, null);
        addOverlayItem(overlayItem);
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView)
    {
        //---when user lifts his finger---
        if (event.getAction() == 1) 
        {
            GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
            (int) event.getX(),
            (int) event.getY());

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," +
                    p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try 
            {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6, p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

                String strCompleteAddress= "";
                if (addresses.size() > 0)
                {
                    for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++)
                    strCompleteAddress+= addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                }
                Log.i("MyLocTAG => ", strCompleteAddress);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), strCompleteAddress, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.i("MyLocTAG => ", "this is the exception part");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        return false;
    }*/
}

//An AsyncTask class for accessing the GeoCoding Web Service
private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>>
{
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) 
    {
        // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            //Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 3);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return addresses;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) 
    {
        //Getting Reference to MapView of the layout activity_main
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview1);

        // Setting ZoomControls
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        // Getting MapController for the MapView
        MapController mc = mapView.getController();

        // Getting Drawable object corresponding to a resource image
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin);

        // Getting Overlays of the map
        List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();

        // Creating an ItemizedOverlay
        LocationOverlay locationOverlay = new LocationOverlay(drawable,getBaseContext());

        // Clearing the overlays
        overlays.clear();

        if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Redraws the map to clear the overlays
            mapView.invalidate();
        }

        // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
        for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++)
        {
            Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

            // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
            GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int)(address.getLatitude()*1E6), (int)(address.getLongitude()*1E6));

            String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
                address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                address.getCountryName());

            // Creating an OverlayItem to mark the point
            OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(p, "Location",addressText);

            // Adding the OverlayItem in the LocationOverlay
            locationOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);

            // Adding locationOverlay to the overlay
            overlays.add(locationOverlay);

            // Locate the first location
            if(i==0)
            mc.animateTo(p);
            mc.setZoom(15);
        }

        // Redraws the map
        mapView.invalidate();
    }
}

public void FindLocation(String plaats)
{

    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());    
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(
            plaats, 5);
        //String add = "";
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            coordinates[counter] = (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6);
            counter++;
            coordinates[counter] = (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6);
            counter++;
        }    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

a few hints:

- On FindLocation add an else to catch not found locations:

  public void FindLocation(String plaats) {

  ```
          Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());    
          try {
              List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(
              plaats, 5);
          //String add = "";
          if (addresses.size() > 0) {
              coordinates[counter] = (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6);
              counter++;
              coordinates[counter] = (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6);
              counter++;
          } else {
             Log.v(TAG, "Site " + plaats + " not found!");
          }
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```

Also in onCreate() loop over already defined locations, not the whole array:

```
 for (int i = 0; i<count; i+=2)
 {
     point = new GeoPoint(coordinates[i], coordinates[i+1]);
     OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "new place added", null);
     itemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem(overlayItem);
 }
```

Comment: but is there anything new on the LogCat? all points are created?

Comment: if no points are created seems like geoCoder.getFromLocationName() isn't returning anything. Try with some well known place you get results with. Also add some Log.d("MAP", ...) lines on all methods to see the actual calling stack and some more in the loops to see the actual variables stored data.

Comment: It is just not taking over the strings, only the last string is known by the class map...
when i change my method FindLocation to this:
   

 public void FindLocation(String plaats) 
    {
    Toast.makeText(Map.this, plaats,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
It only shows the last inserted place.

Comment: I've just noticed you initialize the plaats var each time onClick get executed whith plaats = new String[20];. I guess you wanted to initialize it only the first time. Wrap this with an if (plaats == null) {}